# How do you summon the Killer Bunny on Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I know that the Killer Bunny can be summoned with commands in Java Edition, like so:

```
summon minecraft:rabbit ~ ~ ~ {RabbitType:99}
```

Is it possible to do this on Bedrock Edition? If so, how?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure,  but I don't think that the Killer Bunny has been added into the game. I think the code is only in Java Edition.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, as of 1.16 Bedrock Edition, the Killer Bunny is **not able to spawn**. This means you can't get it using spawn eggs, or commands. There is actually another varient of bunny that you can spawn using commands, and that is the Giant rabbit. According to [minecraft.fandom.com](https://r.search.yahoo.com/_ylt=A2KLfSlVbp5gujUA42dXNyoA;_ylu=Y29sbwNiZjEEcG9zAzEEdnRpZAMEc2VjA3Nj/RV=2/RE=1621024470/RO=10/RU=https%3A%2F%2Fminecraft.fandom.com%2Fwiki%2FRabbit%23%3A%7E%3Atext%3DThe%2520Killer%2520Bunny%2520does%2520not%2520spawn%2520naturally%2520and%2Cfollows%253A%2520%252F%2520summon%2520rabbit%2520%7E%2520%7E%2520%7E%2520minecraft%253Agiant_rabbit./RK=2/RS=VDXSaOVkXPgf8b_R7OJKDnBMZog-), you can spawn the giant rabbit using this command: /summon rabbit ~ ~ ~ minecraft:giant_rabbit

Comment: Is the giant rabbit hostile? I've never heard of that easter egg before. Get it?

Comment: No, I don't believe that the giant rabbit is hostile. The reason that you may not know this, is because a lot of people focus mainly on Minecraft Java Edition, and don't pay too much attention to the Minecraft Bedrock Edition features. That, or many people use Minecraft Java Edition  because it is easier to record things in it (Like replay mods).

Comment: That is quite interesting.